# Use an integer & string to rails date/time helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two values saved in my database that I would like to use as a Date helper in Rails.

For example, `num` is an Integer value of `2` and `period` is a String a value of `days`. Id like to use them as follows:

```
2.days.from_now
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
num.period.from_now
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) to invoke a dynamic method name:

```
num.send(period).from_now
```